# facing problems with vi editor in CLT

Tags: keyboard, editor, vi

My keyboard keys are not working properly in Command line terminal when i use "vi" command to edit a file or write a program.backspace doesn't work. arrow keys doesn't work and are printing A B C D instead of moving the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install it first, because by default `vim-tiny` is installed.

`sudo apt-get install vim`